# Windows XP moved to a pc with only USB ports: can't login USB keyboard will install driver only after login)

Tags: windows-xp, login

That's it.

This Windows xp used without problems a ps/2 keyboard.

Now I've moved it (using noton ghost) to a newer pc (without ps/2) and I think that I'll have usb keyboard driver installed ONLY after successful login.

What can I do? :S

Comment: I was about to tell you to hit WINDOWS KEY + U to bring up utility manager, which would let you bring up the onscreen keyboard. That would've been silly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Ensure that "USB Legacy support" or "USB Keyboard Support" is enabled
>   in the BIOS. Without it, Windows requires a driver to be installed in
>   order to make use of a USB keyboard.

My answer comes from [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/29745-35-keyboard-responding-safe-mode) and it helped me a lot.

Comment: This requires a keyboard to enable.  The solution would have to be find a keyboard that does work, if required, use a docking station to get ps2 support

Comment: @Ramhound: The BIOS will recognize the USB keyboard without drivers unless there is something wrong with the computer.

Comment: The pc, before booting windows, allowed me to use the keyboard.
That's really strange but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, one cannot "move" Windows XP to another computer. Even if you get it working, Windows will ask to be activated, meaning that you would need to shell out for the price of a new Windows XP license (and I am not at all sure that this is even available).

Second, you could first install the USB driver on the old computer using the Add New Hardware wizard, and only then "move" it.

Third, you could reinstall XP from scratch on the new computer, using the installation CD.

Fourth, you could buy a USB PS/2 Adapter.